# AJAX POST request Using Variables in the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having an issue with making a post request with a project I created to take in contact info from a form. When I run the function to make the post request I get nothing back in the console. heres the code:

```
function postContact(token) {
firstName = $('#agentfirst').val();
lastName = $('#agentlast').val();
workNumber = $('#agentwork').val();
cellNumber = $('#agentcell').val();
faxNumber = $('#agentfax').val();
agentEmail = $('#agentemail').val();
agentLicense = $('#agentlicense').val();
companyName = $('#companyname').val();
streetAddress = $('#companyaddress').val();
addressCity = $('#companycity').val();
addressState = $('#companystate').val();
addressZip = $('#companyzip').val();
companyLicense = $('#companylicense').val();

var data = `{
"categoryId": 9,
"companyName": "${companyName}",
"personalContactLicense": {
"licenseNumber": "${companyLicense}"
},
"businessContactLicense": {
"licenseNumber": "${agentLicense}"
},
"noSpam": true,
"firstName": "${firstName}",
"lastName": "${lastName}",
"accessLevel": "1",
"currentMailingAddress": {
"street1": "${streetAddress}",
"city": "${addressCity}",
"state": "${addressState}",
"zip": "${addressZip}"
},
"workPhone": "${workNumber}",
"mobilePhone": "${cellNumber}",
"faxNumber": "${faxNumber}",
"businessEmail": "${agentEmail}"
}`;

var options = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/businessContacts",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/javascript",
"Authorization": token
},
"processData": true,
"data": data
};
console.log(options.data);

$.ajax(options).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
}
```

I dont if the problem is me using varibles in the options for the ajax call but any help or being pointed in the right direction would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have form, you can simply do

```
var form_data = $('#yourformId').serialize();
```

And on your ajax options, simply include this

```
data: form_data,
```

I am not sure, how you are handling this ajax call and how you are preparing your response. You can debug to see where you is the problem.

Comment: How I have it setup on is onsubmit my function is ran. In the console I get back: XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/businessContacts".

Comment: is it browser specific or happening on all browser ?

Comment: I get the XHR failed loading on chrome. On internet explorer i get DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. And on firefox it just clears the console when i submit